# my own print command in c++

Tags: c++, printing, command, cout

I want to create my own printing command in c++, but my code doesnt work. What must I do ?

```
int main()
{

string command;
string textToPrint;
main:

std::cout <<"> ";
std::cin >> command;


if(command=="say("+textToPrint+");") {
    std::cout<< textToPrint << endl;    
}

system("echo.");
goto main;
return 0;

}
```

> When I type say(textToPrint); i want to print only textToPrint

Comment: *but my code doesnt work* what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: cout doesnt prints the textToPrint

Comment: so you want your program to magically match an expression and put the right part in textToPrint ?

Comment: If you want to implement it this was try to use regular expressions. In line `(command=="say("+textToPrint+");")` compiler doesn't assign anything to `textToPrint`. It just leaves empty.

Comment: Oh, okey, i understand, but how can i set textToPrint as a text from userinput ?

Comment: @adamhladik: You're going to need to *parse* the entered command. You need to get the command off the front, check that it's equal to "say", and then extract the string parameter that goes with it. It's not as easy as it looks.

Comment: Can you show me example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `textToPrint` is never assigned, your code tests if the command is "say();", and in that case, outputs an empty line.
In order to make it work, you need to explicitly parse your command. There are lots of ways to do that, but a simple way is:

```
int main()
{
  string command;
  string textToPrint;

  string commandPrefix = "say(";     
  string commandSuffix = ");";

  while (true) {
    std::cout <<"> ";
    std::cin >> command;

    // see if the command starts with "say("
    auto prefixIdx = command.find(commandPrefix);
    if (0 != prefixIdx) continue;

    // see if the command ends with ");"
    auto suffixIdx = command.rfind(commandSuffix);
    auto expectedSuffixIdx = command.size() - commandSuffix.size();
    if (expectedSuffixIdx != suffixIdx) continue;

    auto textToPrintLength = expectedSuffixIdx - commandPrefix.size();
    textToPrint = command.substr(commandPrefix.size(), textToPrintLength);
    std::cout<< textToPrint << std::endl;    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `textToPrint` is never assigned a value.

Comment: Seems like he got it working without the assignment :)

Comment: Fixed... it wouldn't feel very complete if it kept printing empty lines ;)